# In Oracle, why can I not find the SH schema or any of its tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, schema

In my school assignment I am asked to create two tables with this code:

```
create table sales1 tablespace ts_harddrive as select * from sh.sales;
create table sales2 tablespace ts_harddrive as select * from sh.sales;
```

Oracle returns the error "table or view does not exist" starting at "sh.sales".

I know that SH is a sample schema that should be automatically installed during normal Oracle installation, but when I expand the "users" category within Oracle, I do not see SH or any of the other sample schemas. I am currently logged in as system in a test user.

I wish I could attempt reinstalling the sample schemas, but this is in a virtual machine run by my university, so my level of access to anything (especially if anything goes wrong) is unknown/nil.

Any ideas on what I can do or what the problem is?

Comment: Yes - tell your professor/teacher, it is their responsibility to make sure the standard SH schema is installed on the university's VM if they assign you homework based on that. Other than that, SO is for specific **programming** questions, not the right place for this kind of question.

Comment: Oh ok, I apologize. Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you use a personal computer, you may download and install Oracle for free (if it is for learning) and not depend on the university's system at all.

Comment: Well, that is true, and I've been trying that for months, but I have been inundated with gobs of errors trying to do that, at least following my professor's instructions. Even she has been unable to help me with the errors, so I have had no choice but to use the VM version :/

Comment: Now - are you sure the schema does not exist? Perhaps you simply need to be granted privileges on it. Something to discuss with your professor and/or the university DBA. (The professor should have taken care of this for all students though.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sh schema is designed for only enterprise editions where partitioning option is installed, you can't operate on the schema using standard edition or express edition of the database.So , i suggest you to install enterprise edition of the database.